# Python Selecting Data in a List within a List

Tags: python, list, select

```
list = [['John',3]['Carey',4]['Jake',3]]
```

I'm looking for a way to select the data of a list within a list.

I want to be able to get the values `3,4,3` and convert them into an int.

If I try:

```
print list[1::2] 
returns [['Carey',4]
```

I only want every second value of a list within a list.

Any suggestions?

(I can't use `filter()` but I can use list comprehensions)

Comment: There should be commas between list elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the numbers like so (and don't call it `list`; that's the name of the type):

```
[ i for [_, i] in lst ]
```

I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by, "convert them into an int."

Comment: I wanted to convert the numerical values in the list into a type: int so that I could plug it into a mathematical function

Answer (score 0):

This one is fine

```
l = [['John','3'],['Carey','4'],['Jake','3']] 
for i in xrange(len(l)):
    print int(l[i][1])
```

I hope I understand your question